# How to configure Eslint to give an error if prop is not defined in component definition's propType?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

Suppose I've a component like this:

```
const abc = ({text}) => <p>{text}</p>;
abc.propTypes = { text: PropType.string };
```

In another file where I import it:

```
<Abc text={'some text'} />
```

Everything is great. However, Is there a way for Vscode or eslint to give an error if I use a prop that doesn't exist, like so:

```
<Abc text={'some text'} rrrr={3} />
```

`rrrr` is a prop that neither gets used nor it's defined in propTypes.

If eslint or vscode could give notify me that this prop is invalid. It'd be great.

Comment: Can you share your ESLint config file as by default, ESLint gives the error.

Comment: the error is if you try to use a prop in a component's declaration without first declaring in its proptype. But I'm talking about using importing the component and using it

Comment: Probably not as it is by design to be able to pass *any* prop to any component. A fairly common design pattern is to pass all extra props on to rendered children components. It'd be a bit excessive to try and drill down and test that all occurrences of passed props *are actually used*.

Comment: not necessarily used, but declared in prototype at least. also this can be an optional opt-in type of feature

Comment: i guess something similar to no-unsed var in eslint but no-undeclared-prop